# How to update nginx-ingress controller so that latest ingress paths are used?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

After updating the ingress paths from '/' to '/test', the new path does not work and i still keep getting redirected to the old '/' path. Any ideas on how to update nginx-ingress controller for updated ingresses?

Update:
I get following in my ingress-controller logs

```
kubectl logs --tail=10 nginx-ingress-controller-6b5498d8dc-vsdpl
E0923 17:03:11.440951       9 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0923 17:03:25.947663       9 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0923 17:03:35.337064       9 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0923 17:03:39.800610       9 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0923 17:03:45.983141       9 main.go:49] Error getting node 192.168.0.81: nodes "192.168.0.81" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot get resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0923 17:03:57.179763       9 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot list resource "configmaps" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0923 17:03:57.609798       9 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0923 17:04:10.422852       9 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0923 17:04:20.552808       9 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E0923 17:04:24.767965       9 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.networking.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-ingress" cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
```

Comment: Check the `nginx.conf` file in nginx ingress controller pod

Comment: @ArghyaSadhuThank you for the reply. The nginx.conf file had old '/' path so i changed it to '/dev' but still didn't work. May be i need to restart nginx controller after updating nginx.conf?

Comment: You updated `nginx.conf` file or the ingress resource? Did you update in all replicas of nginx pod?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu i updated my ingress first with the new paths. But i was still being redirected to old path. So then i checked the nginx.conf and it still had old paths so i updated nginx.conf too. There is just one replica of nginx pod

Comment: AFAIK nginx can detect updates in nginx.conf without restart. Did you check logs og nginx ingress controller pod?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu i just posted my logs. Please see above my updated question

Comment: Doesn't the nginx ingress controller not even use nginx.conf?  It uses config-maps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The service account used by nginx ingress controller does not seem to have permission. use the below `clusterrolebinding`

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:nginx-ingress
```

Just a note this is essentially giving cluster admin privilege to that service account and can be made more fine grained.

Comment: Yes now in the logs i saw that it got updated. But now /static works but /test gives The requested resource was not found on this server.

Comment: I would suggest to ask a new question for that with ingress yamls and logs from nginx ingress controller pods

Comment: It worked the ingress controller reloaded after defining clusterrole binding. Thanks a lot !